# Bash script that creates a file with a introduced name

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, console

I was wondering how to create a bash script that asks the user for the desired name, and then, creates a file with that name.

something like:

```
introduce name: test [enter]
(then use that name as the name of the final zip)
zip -9 test.zip *
(creating the file)
"test.zip" crated.
(print out that message)
end
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you looked at any "beginning scripting" tutorials?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wrote something like this

```
read -p 'introduce name:' input
ext=$(sed -n 's/\(^.[^$]*\)\(.\{3\}$\)/\2/p' <<< $input)
if [ $ext = zip ]
    then zip -9 $input *
elif [ $ext = cbz ]
    then zip -9 $input *
elif [ $ext = rar ]
    then rar a $input *
else 
    echo "I just zip, cbz and rar, sorry :("
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
read -p 'introduce name:' input
zip -9 $input.zip *
```

Check

```
help -m read | less
```

---

If you are a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) beginniner, some good pointers to start learning :

FAQ: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ
Guide: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide
Ref: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
Check your script: http://www.shellcheck.net/

And avoid recommendations of people saying to learn with `tldp.org` web site, the tldp bash guide is outdated, and in some cases just plain wrong.